# How many functions $f : B\to B$ , with $|B| = n$ exist that are also an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was trying some exercises on relations and came across this problem. I thought as every equivalence relation on a set $B$ has to be reflexive, $f(b) = b$ has to hold for all $b\in B$. But the way functions are defined, every $f(b)$ can only have 1 value, that is if $f(x) = y$ and $f(x) = y'$ then $y = y'$. So my conclusion was every equivalence relation that is a function, is of the form : $\{(b,b) | b\in B\}$ , and therefore there are "n" such functions. Is this correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The argument is almost correct. The only mistake is that since you have $f(b)=b$ for every $b \in B$, the conclusion is that there is only one function satisfying the property, not $n$.

Comment: @Daniel Oh yes, exactly.. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct

Since the relation is reflexive you have $f(x)=x$ so the function is the identity function.

Clearly  there is only one such function regardless of the size of $B$